# Recommended location of business logic after an $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coding-style, jsonp

At first, I placed all my magic as a call from *success* function but I just realized that one can append *done(...)* after the call (and I believe there's a *ready* too).

Where would the recommended location for doing the business magic be?

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://...",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function () { doMagic(1); },
  ready: function () { doMagic(2); },
  ...
}).done(function () { doMagic(3); });
```

Comment: It would be in `done()`.

Comment: I don't know where you got `ready` from - it's not in the jQuery docs. And the `success` option is the same as `.done()` here. Anything you provide for `success` just gets used for internally calling `.done()` on the internal deferred object used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a "right way", but most of what I have seen recommends using `.done(...)` because it is cleaner and easier to read.  The reason is because it takes the `success` function out of the middle of the block of code for the actual AJAX call.

In other words, it is easier to read this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://...",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  ...
}).done(function(data){
    // SOME VERY LONG FUNCTION HERE
});
```

than to read this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://...",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){
    // SOME VERY LONG FUNCTION HERE
  },
  ...
});
```

---

That said, if the function to be called actually does anything significant (i.e. more than just dumping the result into some HTML element), I would use a named function and reference it from here, and in that case I think it would be easier to read this:

```
function OnSuccess(data) {
    // SOME VERY LONG FUNCTION HERE
}

$.ajax({
  url: "http://...",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: OnSuccess,
  ...
});
```

than to read this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://...",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  ...
}).done(OnSuccess);
```

(Actually, it would be better to namespace the function (and *all* of your "business logic"), like `Business.Model.OnSuccess`, but I left that out because it isn't really part of the answer)

Comment: `but I left that out because it isn't really part of the answer` - true, but it's a good thing to point out. You're relating it to business logic so it's not bad to say

Comment: Very nice answer. And, although off-topic, the last comment **should** be made as often as possible. I myself forget (or am too lazy) to put stuff in namespaces because "it's just a small test thingy". Head down in shame...